в коде есть ошибки?
Написал код и вместо какого-либо print() мне ничего не пишет, почему?
transport = input('Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): ').lower
speed = int(input('Введите скорость транспорта: '))


if transport == 'машина':
    if speed < 80:
        print('Нет нарушений')
    else:
        print('Нарушение!')

if transport == 'мотоцикл':
    if speed < 60:
            print('Нет нарушений')
    else:
        print('Нарушение!')


transport = input('Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): ').lower             эта строка должна быть над  'speed' но почему то не вставилась. Такое происходит не только с этим кодом, но есть и те которые работают.

Вы знаете как вызывать методы и функции?

вставь print(transport) и посмотри что там. Элементарные методы отладки надо бы уметь.

Ох уж эти языки с нечёткой типизацией... Нормальный язык бы сразу обругался, что функции и строки сравнивать нельзя )

@CrazyElf ну по крайней мере линтеры указывают на это

ты забыл () после lower, поэтому не работает

Вот по сути достаточно было бы такого комментария от завсегдатаев и знатоков питона, чтобы решить типичную проблему новичка с опечаткой...

спасибо, я забыл про это.

Фактически, @kabanery указал в своём ответе, как решить проблему в представленном коде -- достаточно было поставить скобки после указания функции lower, чтобы эта функция была действительно вызвана для строки, полученной после вызова метода input, и была бы получена требуемая строка в нижнем регистре.
Без скобок же в переменную transport запишется ссылка на встроенный метод lower.
Также следовало бы задуматься о возможной реальной причине отсутствия вывода.
Дело в том, что условия if не охватывают все возможные значения переменной transport, то есть даже при исправлении первоначальной опечатки в коде весьма вероятно, что программа ничего не напечатает, если к примеру пользователь неверно введёт один из указанных вариантов.
То есть, прежде всего следовало бы добавить вывод для любого необрабатываемого значения transport.
Тогда в коде с первоначальной опечаткой можно будет получить следующий вывод:
transport = input('Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): ').lower
speed = int(input('Введите скорость транспорта: '))

if transport == 'машина':
    if speed < 80:
        print('Нет нарушений')
    else:
        print('Нарушение!')
elif transport == 'мотоцикл':
    if speed < 60:
            print('Нет нарушений')
    else:
        print('Нарушение!')
else:   # необработанный случай
    print("Неизвестный транспорт:", transport)

Вывод:
Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): машина
Введите скорость транспорта: 55
Неизвестный транспорт: <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fe390462090>

Сразу видна проблема с кодом.
После исправления опечатки lower() возможны варианты:

Необрабатываемый ввод:

Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): МОТО
Введите скорость транспорта: 66
Неизвестный транспорт: мото


Корректный ввод:

Введите вид транспорта(мотоцикл или машина): Машина
Введите скорость транспорта: 90
Нарушение!


после того как я написал тс и скорость у меня сразу же просит написать все повторно и так же не выводит print. но все равно спасибо за ответ! буду искать в чем дело.

Что значит написал тс и скорость, то, что вы ввели требуемые данные?  И что значит просит написать все повторно?  У вас линейный код без циклов.
